# Addin failing to install in monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I wrote an addin using [AddinMaker](https://github.com/mhutch/MonoDevelop.AddinMaker) for `monodevelop` and wile it works perfectly in debug mode, I can't manage to install the package version.

I packaged the release version in the `./bin/Release` folder [according to the official tutorial](http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/publishing-an-addin/)

```
 mdtool setup pack <myaddin>.dll
```

When installing the addin usig the `mpack` file, I get the always unhelpful `the installation failed` message without any other information.

From what I understand, AddinMaker uses `Nuget` packages. Do I need to run a special command for the packaging?

**Is there a way to find what went wrong with the installation?**